# What is the difference between a ‘signature’ and an ‘autograph’?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

A cashier asked my friend for her autograph when she was signing for a credit card purchase (straight-faced, so it wasn’t a joke). This seemed strange to me, as I’ve only ever heard the word “signature” used in this situation. Is this usage more common than I realized?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is a common joke for register operators just trying to put a little something personal into an otherwise mind-numbing  (and stressful) job. They might also ask for "your John Hancock" in the USA. With repetition it comes out straight-faced.

Comment: What about the dictionary definitions do you not understand?  What research have you done thus far?  You might want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on [how to ask on-topic questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Similar to how all thumbs are fingers but not all fingers are thumbs, an autograph is a type of signature.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[signature](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/signature)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A person's name written in a distinctive way as a form of identification in authorizing a cheque or document or concluding a letter.
>
>    *‘the signature of a senior manager’*
>
> ***[autograph](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/autograph)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A signature, especially that of a celebrity written as a memento for an admirer.
>
>    *‘fans surged around the car asking for autographs’*

As for the cashier, it is possible that they simply did not know the difference or even that there is a difference and, having heard another cashier making the all-too-common *autograph* joke, thought that it was the preferred or accepted term.  Or, maybe they just aren't very good at making jokes.